# Wordpress - how do I know if a menu item has children?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress theme with nested submenus. I need to make the elements with no children visually different from the ones that have children. Right now I have this menu, but that could change:

```
A
  a1
  a2
B
  b1
  b2
C
```

As you can see, A and B have children. C doesn't - I need it to be different in the CSS level.

Ideally, I would like to have a `has-children` class in A and B, but not in C.

So far I've managed to create a "Menu Walker" PHP class that I can instantiate and pass to [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) . Its constructor looks like this:

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    ...
    if(??? $item has children???) {
      // I know what to do here
    }
  }
}
```

So, how do I tell whether `$item` has children, or is a leaf?

EDIT: this question was answered by someone called "keesiemeijer" in the Wordpress forums. I'm leaving this bounty expired just in case he wants to reclaim it. Otherwise, I'll be marking my own answer as valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked in the [WordPress forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-know-if-a-menu-item-has-children-or-is-a-leaf?replies=3) and keesiemeijer pointed me to [this other post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_nav_menu-add-a-parent-class?replies=7), in which they did the following:

Instead of modifying `start_el`, they modified `display_element`, adding the following two lines (lines 37-38 [here](http://pastebin.com/DVEcci3e)):

```
//display this element (THESE ARE NOT THE LINES)
if ( is_array( $args[0] ) )
  $args[0]['has_children'] = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );

// THESE TWO ARE THE LINES:               
if( ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] ) )
  array_push($element->classes,'parent');
```

I've left the previous two lines as a spacial reference, and also as a comment to other answers in this post. It seems that wordpress is "trying" to set a ´has_children´ property in `$args`, but it's either doing it wrong or in a way I don't understand. In any case, that `has_children` parameter is never passed down to `start_el` (see sample var_dump of an $args [here](https://gist.github.com/1471990))

This might be a bug on the Wordpress version I've got (3.2.1) and might have been fixed in the most recent version.

In any case, the answer I got in the Wordpress forum is the one that helped me fix it, so I consider this settled. I'll wait for the bounty to expire just in case keesiemeijer wants to put his answer here.

Comment: (1) It's interesting that this remains unresolved in WP's codebase quite some time on (as of current writing, in WP 3.5.1 the behavior is unchanged). (2) The problem is that `$args[0]` is in fact an object. I may submit a patch; it should be handled regardless, presumably with an `elseif (is_object($args[0])) { $args[0]->has_children = ... }`.

Comment: And, a little digging reveals that someone has already submitted that patch (see [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21534))—for some reason, it hasn't gotten pushed into the core yet.

Comment: And, for the sake of anybody else who runs into this, I've added that solution as [another answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16084680/564181), but referencing yours, since I'd have had a much harder time figuring out what the issue was without your answer.

Answer (score 34):

Add this to `functions.php` it will add the 'dropdown' class to parents

**New way beter for performance**

```
function menu_set_dropdown( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
    $last_top = 0;
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $obj ) {
        // it is a top lv item?
        if ( 0 == $obj->menu_item_parent ) {
            // set the key of the parent
            $last_top = $key;
        } else {
            $sorted_menu_items[$last_top]->classes['dropdown'] = 'dropdown';
        }
    }
    return $sorted_menu_items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'menu_set_dropdown', 10, 2 );
```

**Old: intensive on the DB**

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'check_for_submenu', 10, 2);
function check_for_submenu($classes, $item) {
    global $wpdb;
    $has_children = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(meta_id) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND meta_value='".$item->ID."'");
    if ($has_children > 0) array_push($classes,'dropdown'); // add the class dropdown to the current list
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Note that this method adds another database query for each of your menu items and can slow down your site if you have a lot of menu items!

Comment: @Ahrengot see my new way far better for the Databse ;)

Comment: it has no effect in wp 3.6 ? any thing else to add or remove ? im using wp_nav_menu()

Comment: @RashidShafique it works in 3.6 Did you asign a menu in the `wp-admin`? Tested it on a clean install with `twentyeleven` and no other plugin

Comment: Great solution, however does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work on sub-sub-menus? (a dropdown withing a dropdown)

Answer (score 26):

Simple you use this way:

Explain:
I create menu with "walker":

```
$walker = new Nav_Walker;
wp_nav_menu(array(
        'container'=>'nav',
        'container_class'=>'menu',
        'menu_class'=>'list-unstyled list-inline',
        'walker'=>$walker
    ));
```

Class Walker:

```
class Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{ 
      public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
    {
        if($args->walker->has_children)
        {
            //code...
        }   
    }
}
```

We have object 'walker', you can *var_dump($args)* to see more things.
I'm using for my project !

Comment: Welcome to SO, starrynight and thank you for your first answer. Some advice to get better scored for your answers: Include an explanation as to _why_ your code will solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 14):

It seems that the problem has finally been addressed. The latest Wordpress beta as of current writing 4.0, has updated the Walker_Nav_Menu class and added a `$has_children` property.

```
/**
 * Whether the current element has children or not.
 *
 * To be used in start_el().
 *
 * @since 4.0.0
 * @access protected
 * @var bool
 */
protected $has_children;
```

So, we don't need to hack `function display_element(...)` anymore.

Comment: Yes it's added automatically now .

Answer (score 6):

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    ...
    if($args['has_children']) {
      // I know what to do here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that will not work. For two reasons - first, `$args` is a `stdObject`, not an `array` - so the syntax would be `$args->has_children`. And second, `$args` doesn't have a `has_children` attribute (I checked using `var_dump($args)`). Neither it or `$item` seem to have such an attribute.

Comment: @kikito could you post var_dump($args) results?

Comment: @kikito strange it has "has_children" arg on my end.

Comment: `if ($args->walker->has_children)`

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'menu_has_children', 10, 2);

function menu_has_children($sorted_menu_items, $args) {
    $parents = array();
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $obj )
            $parents[] = $obj->menu_item_parent;
    foreach ($sorted_menu_items as $key => $obj)
        $sorted_menu_items[$key]->has_children = (in_array($obj->ID, $parents)) ? true : false;
    return $sorted_menu_items;
}
```

Then in your walker your can check if $item->has_children is true or false

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Kikito's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8492232/564181) gets the trick done, but not in the most reusable way. In my view, the better approach is like this:

```
function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output) {
    // the first few lines of the method...

    //display this element; handle either arrays or objects gracefully
    if ( is_array( $args[0] ) )
        $args[0]['has_children'] = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );

    elseif ( is_object($args[0]) )
        $args[0]->has_children =  ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );

    // the rest of the method...
}
```

Overriding `Walker::display_element()` is the right move, but it's better to actually address the problem at the root of the issue rather than simply tacking a class on at this point, for two reasons. First, the real problem isn't a missing class but rather the un-patched bug in WordPress that Kikito noted: the problem is that `$args[0]` isn't always an array. That appears to be the typically expected type for `Walker::display_element()`, but we're actually dealing here with `Walker_Nav_Menu::display_element()`, and in that case `args` ends up being passed in as a standard object type rather than an array type. As such, we simply need to add the `has_children` element using object notation instead of array notation. Problem solved![1]

Adding that `elseif` accounts for the ordinary Nav Menu case. This is the same form that will hopefully make it into the core class in [this patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21534), at which point you'll no longer have to extend it. They should probably patch it further to account for the case that `$args[0]` is neither an array nor an object, but I don't expect to see that happen.

Second, in order to keep good separation of concerns between the various methods, classes should really be added in the `start_el()` method or elsewhere, since `display_element()` isn't doing any of the class handling.

As a result, you can then override `start_el()` however you like: you can add your own custom classes, or ignore elements entirely, or supply custom text, or whatever you like. (In my case, I'm working around an existing Javascript menu implementation that has very specific classing requirements based on parents *and* children, so I can't just add the same classes to everything that has a child – which is precisely why this separation of concerns matters.) In my code:

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $has_children = (is_object($args) && $args->has_children) || (is_array($args) &&  $args['has_children']);
    if ($has_children) {
        // do whatever you need to do
    }

    // everything else the method does...
}
```

---

[1] This is of course one of the potential pitfalls of dynamically typed languages like PHP... it's not a problem, as long as you're careful. The WordPress developers weren't careful here.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the overhead of a hard query or function, you can do this in jQuery:

```
(function() {
    // Add 'has_children' class to menus
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.menu-item').has('ul.sub-menu'), function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('has_children');
    });
})();
```

Comment: A server-side PHP function almost certainly adds less "overhead" than a jQuery call on the front end, *especially* if you factor in caching. Moreover, this solution (1) assumes that jQuery is already in use and (2) that doing something like this wouldn't interfere with any other menu-focused JS on the back end.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho jQuery is loaded with WordPress. Adding a new class has no effect on backend. On high load servers, another query is something you want to avoid. And of course, this is but one solution to decide on using.

Comment: Ah, good point, I had forgotten about that (as I always end up pulling the shipped version and pushing my own because the shipped version is almost never latest).

Answer (score 3):

```
    /**
     * @see My_Nav_Walk::start_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Menu item data object.
     * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param int $current_page Menu item ID.
     * @param object $args
     * @url:http://www.liyinqing.com
     */
class My_Nav_Walk extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    // Check our custom has_children property.here is the points
    if ( $args->has_children ) {
      $attributes .= ' class="menu parent"';
    }

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }

  function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
    if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {/.here is the points
      $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
    }
    return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
  }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is one of the first results on Google search, has been referenced in other webpages and most the of the answers here are outdated I thought I would post this answer.

**start_el()** has **classes** as part of **$item** object. So You can add this in start_el():

```
   if(in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes) && $depth != 0)
   {
       // Your Code
   }
```

Note that **$depth** is not required in the conditions but if removed your code will be applied to the first item (i.e. item with 0 depth).

As for the compatibility part, the class **'menu-item-has-children'** has been added to [WordPress 3.7 (October 2013)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/25602) and I have tested it on the latest WordPress 4.4 (as of the time of posting this answer).

Comment: How is $depth set in this example?

Comment: It is supplied by start_el:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/start_el/

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of rewriting core functionality** of the `Walker_Nav_Menu` or `Walker` class methods let's just use good old class inheritance.

#### The Code

```php
class Has_Child_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    public function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, &$output ) {
        if ( ! $element ) {
            return;
        }
        $element->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[ $element->{$this->db_fields['id']} ] );
        parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }
}
```

#### How It Works

1. We create a new class `Has_Child_Walker_Nav_Menu` that inherits from `Walker_Nav_Menu` that in turn inherits from `Walker`.
2. We override the `Walker->display_element()` method with our own function since it the first method called for each individual menu-items while we are walking the menu item tree.
3. In our `display_element()` method we create a new property `has_children` on the `$element` a.k.a. menu item. This makes the property available on the `$item` object in both `start_el()` and `end_el()` methods, this means it also passed to the filters called by `start_el()`.
4. The value of our new `has_children` property value is calculated the same way the `Walker` instance property `has_children` is determined.
5. Lastly we call the `display_element()` method on the parent `Walker_Nav_Menu`... well actually grandparent `Walker` since `Walker_Nav_Menu` doesn't have it's own `display_element()` method. We make sure to pass all the values from our `display_element()` method to the `Walker->display_element()` method.

**That's it!**

Now we have `$item->has_children` available anywhere we might need it including filters.

#### Example Usage

**The Menu**

```php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'main_nav',
        'container_class' => 'main-nav',
        'walker'          => new Has_Child_Walker_Nav_Menu()
    )
);
```

**The Filter**

```php
function my_menu_dropdown( $output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    if ( $item->has_children ) {
        $output .= '<a href="#" class="expand-menu-toggle"><i class="fal fa-angle-down"></i></a>';
    }
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_menu_dropdown', 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Start_el function, my function follow that function to run query. 
I have a function will count sub menu of parent menu by ID.

```
function nav_count_children($parent_id){
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
            WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' 
            AND meta_value=$parent_id";
    $count_children = $wpdb->get_var( $query );
    return $count_children;
}
```

**Run**
In foreach of wp_get_nav_menu_items function, select ID of parent Menu by $item->menu_item_parent ==0.

It's working for me and very simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution [source](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-know-if-a-menu-item-has-children-or-is-a-leaf?replies=6#post-2987938).

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {

  global $wpdb;
  $children_count = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare("
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta
      WHERE meta_key = %s
      AND meta_value = %d
    ", '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', $item->ID)
  );

  if( $children_count > 0 ) {
    // has children
    $classes[] = 'parent';
  }

  [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this simple code in you walker class

```
 class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
    {
    function start_el(  &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    global $wp_query;
    ////

    ur code in this part 
    ///////
     $depth_classes = array(
        ( $depth == 0 ? 'nav-item' : 'nav-submenu-item' ),
        ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
        ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
        'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
    );
    $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

    // passed classes
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );


     $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
    }
```