# Wordpress nav with w3css frame work

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to implement the below code as a navbar on all the devices. However, I am not able to do so. I am using the w3-css framework with WordPress.

```
<div class="w3-top w3-navbar">
 <ul class="w3-navbar w3-blue-grey w3-left-align ">
   <li><a href="<?php  echo home_url(); ?>" class="w3-padding-large w3-large w3-highway-blue"><i class="topnav-icons fa fa-home w3-margin-right"></i><?php  bloginfo ('name'); ?></a></li>

    <?php 

$args = array(

    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container_class' => 'w3-top',
    'menu_class' => 'w3-navbar',


);


?>

<?php  wp_nav_menu( $args); ?>
 <li class="w3-hide-small w3-right w3-padding-large">+91 987654321</li>
 </ul>
</div>


  <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
  <div id="navDemo" class="w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium w3-top" style="margin-top:51px">
  <ul class="w3-navbar w3-left-align w3-large w3-theme">
   <?php  wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme settings under Appearance->Menus make sure that the location of the menu you wish to output is set to "primary", as you have that as a setting in your `$args` array.

Also, I noticed that your second instance of `wp_nav_menu()` doesn't contain the `$args` array. If you want the first and second navigation menu output to be the same navigation menu, you will need to at least add an array specifying the same location in the "theme_location" index of the array.

Comment: I have already set the menu to primary in my functions.php file. However the chalange is at times menu gets over lapped with <?php  bloginfo ('name'); ?>. And the second menu  is not getting  active on small screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some **filters** in your **functions.php**:

```
function w3css_nav_menu_submenu_css_class_filter ($classes, $args) {
    if ($args->theme_location === 'primary') {
        $classes []= 'w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card';
    }
    else {
        $classes []= 'w3-margin-left';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'w3css_nav_menu_submenu_css_class_filter', 10, 2);

function w3css_nav_menu_css_class_filter ($classes, $item, $args, $depth) {
    if ($args->theme_location === 'primary') {
        $classes []= 'w3-bar-item';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'w3css_nav_menu_css_class_filter', 10, 4);

function w3css_nav_menu_link_attributes_filter ($atts, $item, $args) {
    if ($args->theme_location === 'primary') {
        $atts['class'] = 'w3-button';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'w3css_nav_menu_link_attributes_filter', 10, 3);

// From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448978/wordpress-how-do-i-know-if-a-menu-item-has-children
function menu_set_dropdown( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
    if ($args->theme_location === 'primary') {
        $last_top = 0;
        foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $obj ) {
            // it is a top lv item?
            if ( 0 == $obj->menu_item_parent ) {
                // set the key of the parent
                $last_top = $key;
            } else {
                $sorted_menu_items[$last_top]->classes['w3-dropdown-hover'] = 'w3-dropdown-hover';
            }
        }
    }
    return $sorted_menu_items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'menu_set_dropdown', 10, 2 );
```

Then you can call the menu function in your **header.php**:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="w3-bar w3-bar-item %2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'add_items_class' => '',
    'container'       => false
) );
```

It will be **output** something like:

```
<ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="w3-bar w3-bar-item menu">
    <li id="menu-item-139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-has-children w3-dropdown-hover menu-item-139 w3-bar-item">
        <a href="http://example.org/w3css/" aria-current="page" class="w3-button">Home</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card">
            <li id="menu-item-143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-143 w3-bar-item">
                <a href="http://example.org/about/" class="w3-button">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140 w3-bar-item">
        <a href="http://example.org/about/" class="w3-button">About</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-141" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-141 w3-bar-item">
        <a href="http://example.org/blog/" class="w3-button">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142 w3-bar-item">
        <a href="http://example.org/contact/" class="w3-button">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

By the way, you can copy a lot of functionalities from the W3CSS Starter Template: https://github.com/webarthur/w3css-starter

I hope I've helped. =)